# RewriteRule not redirecting to specified file

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

Here is my rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^rest/v(?:[0-9.]+)/((?:[A-Za-z]+)/(?:[A-Za-z]+)(?:/(?:[A-Za-z0-9])+))?\.(json)$ https://localhost/rest/v1/index.php?url=$1&type=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

It’s something of a mouthful so doesn’t help when trying to debug, but it basically allows a URL like this: http://localhost/rest/v1/users/show/12345.json

I’ve tested it in a regex tester online and it passes. But when I add it to my config file, it doesn’t redirect and gives a 404 message as it tries to find the file 1234.json in the show folder of the users folder.

My error log looks like this:

```
[Tue Oct 27 21:55:16.345721 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4172] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Oct 27 21:55:21.005180 2015] [suexec:notice] [pid 4318] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/suexec)
[Tue Oct 27 21:55:22.001398 2015] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 4319] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Tue Oct 27 21:55:22.001761 2015] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 4319] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Oct 27 21:55:22.014532 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4319] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1j PHP/5.6.3 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Oct 27 21:55:22.014627 2015] [core:notice] [pid 4319] AH00094: Command line: '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/httpd -E /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/logs/error_log -D SSL -D PHP'
[Tue Oct 27 21:55:30.096376 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4323] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50020] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#101019668][rid#10087d4a0/initial] [perdir /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/rest/] add path info postfix: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/rest/v1/users -> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/rest/v1/users/show/12345.json
[Tue Oct 27 21:55:30.096499 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4323] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50020] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#101019668][rid#10087d4a0/initial] [perdir /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/rest/] strip per-dir prefix: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/rest/v1/users/show/12345.json -> v1/users/show/12345.json
[Tue Oct 27 21:55:30.096507 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4323] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50020] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#101019668][rid#10087d4a0/initial] [perdir /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/rest/] applying pattern '^rest/v(?:[0-9.]+)/((?:[A-Za-z]+)/(?:[A-Za-z]+)(?:/(?:[A-Za-z0-9])+))?\\.(json)$' to uri 'v1/users/show/12345.json'
[Tue Oct 27 21:55:30.096521 2015] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 4323] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client ::1:50020] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#101019668][rid#10087d4a0/initial] [perdir /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/rest/] pass through /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/rest/v1/users
```

I’m not really sure what’s going on in the error log but it looks like it passes the regex?

Anyone know why it might not be working?

Comment: Is the [`http://localhost/rest/v1/index.php?url=users/show/12345&type=json`](https://regex101.com/r/cY0wY3/1) expected result for `http://localhost/rest/v1/users/show/12345.json`?

Comment: When I test it online (http://htaccess.madewithlove.be) it forwards to the correct URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this rule in `/rest/` directory. Try this rewrite rule instead without `rest/` in your rule pattern:

```
RewriteRule ^v(?:[0-9.]+)/((?:[A-Za-z]+)/(?:[A-Za-z]+)(?:/(?:[A-Za-z0-9])+))?\.json$ v1/index.php?url=$1&type=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured this out too. Forgot to update the question 